# How to add Cross close button to a dynamic generated kendo tabstrip

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am currently able to create kendo tab dynamically and have external button to remove the tab. Here is my sample code

```
// Create Main Tab
        tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
            animation: {
                open: {
                    effects: "fadeIn"
                }
            }
        });
        tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
        tabStrip.select(0);
```

To create new tab

```
tabStrip.append({ text: "My Title", content: "the content" }); 
//OR 
tabStrip.append({ text: "My Title", contentURL: "http://google.com" });
```

For remove i have separate button with code

```
var tab = tabStrip.select(),
tabStrip.remove(tab);
```

It removes the selected tab. Its Working fine. But my requirement is to add this remove button with caption.

if i have button tag in caption while creating tabstrip then it converts the tag in to a DOM object. for example

```
<ul id="tabstrip">
    <li> Title <button>X</button></li>
</ul>
```

if now kendo tab strip is created is will show a button having "X" caption in the title of tab. but not if i provide same title while creating the tab at run time in the append method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appended text is encoded, and this is why you see the string, but not the HTML element itself. What you can do is after you append the TabStrip element, you can append a button using jQuery, like this:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ArIyO

Comment: Thanks a lot. specially with very quick reply :)